# Intent share is not able to attach image

Tags: android, share-intent

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My text");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(http://onman.ir/colorfinder/sample.jpg));
sendIntent.setType("*/*");
sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share using"));
```

This code is not able to attach image when sharing intent with `Gmail`, also it is giving error when sharing with `Facebook` that share multiple image or a video only. When I change type with `sendIntent.setType("image/*")` then it is opening the share window of `Facebook` but with blank text and image.

Comment: Are you setting <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yeah this permission is already added.

Comment: what error you getting??

Comment: sharing on facebook give me this error: `please attach only a photo or single video`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sharing you can use this code

```
     Intent shareIntent = new Intent();

                   shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                   shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                   shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"abc");
                   shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imagebitmap);
                  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share using"));
```

but if you want to do in facebook it will not working through intent you should use facebook sdk to share image and text

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                                   .setLink(url)
                                   .setCaption(getString(R.string.fb_share))
                                   .setDescription(getString(R.string.fb_share))
                                   .setPicture(
                                                 "https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/11899955_1616850925232395_9146772907853639083_n.jpg?oh=3dd7da7bf03edee84689d66af2024880&oe=56793D62")
                                   .build();
                     uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
                     dismissProgressBar();
```

and in your code you are sharing image url directly first you need to get bitmap then share bitmap instead of url

Comment: But Facebook is one the option in share intent.

Comment: but according to Facebook you can either share image or text using intent  on time so when you want to make share then you should create a custom share dialog and write different code for Facebook sharing.

Comment: only for Facebook you write different code and for reaming all sharing app intent will work .

Answer (score 1):

private void shareImage() {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

```
// If you want to share a png image only, you can do:
// setType("image/png"); OR for jpeg: setType("image/jpeg");
share.setType("image/*");

// Make sure you put example png image named myImage.png in your
// directory
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/myImage.png";

File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));
```

Try this code

Please note that when you use the setType() method, you are enabling Android to filter what apps can share your content. For example, you are sharing a text or URL, the appropriate apps to be shown can be Facebook, Messaging or Email. If you are sharing an image, proper apps can be Instagram, Snapped or Picasa.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == UPLOADIMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        uploadImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (data !=null)
        {
            imageUri=data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            attachmentFile = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Log.e("Attachment Path:", attachmentFile);
            URI = Uri.parse("file://" + attachmentFile);
            cursor.close();

        }
        else {Toast.makeText(TutorForm.this,"Uploading image failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}




    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

OnClickListner

```
 Intent emailIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"+ clientEmail));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,body);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Tutor Registration from App");
        emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUri.toString());
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,URI);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send Via..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");

//set your message
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msgText); 
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
File.separator + "image_name.jpg";
File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Comment: please provide more information (explanation) about your answer.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -1):

This one work for me

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");

            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.share_subject));
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.share_message));

            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(yourimagepath);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: What is the difference? If don't want to add any subject then?